# SPLIT STRING BY NUMBER

Tags: oracle

I have this

`SELECT ('130.067'||'****') as "WIN " 
FROM DUAL ;`

and i need to add a space (" ") in between each number and * to get somethig like this

"1 3 0 . 0 6 7 * * * *"

Comment: Look here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=adding-space-between-a-number-and-a-letter-in-a-record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/350)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         '130.067'||'****', -- String to match
         '([0-9.*])',       -- Match a digit or full stop or star
         ' \1',             -- Replace with space then matched character
         2                  -- Start at the 2nd character
       ) AS win
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/350/0)**:

```
|                   WIN |
|-----------------------|
| 1 3 0 . 0 6 7 * * * * |
```